# How to force specific order of the variables in a waffle chart in R?

Tags: r, waffle-chart

please do forgive me for potentially asking a really silly question but its really important that the data I am representing in my waffle chart is ordered according to the input of my vector.

I am really struggling to force the graph to not reorder into descending order. Any feedback is welcome.

```
library(waffle)
x <- c(A = 5, B = 5, C  = 2, D = 3)
waffle(x, rows=5)
```

Obviously the code above is super basic but I am actually learning this from 0 due to the purpose of the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `rows = 3`, it will be in the right order:

```r
library(waffle)
x <- c(A = 5, B = 5, C  = 2, D = 3)
waffle(x, rows = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately what I am wanting to use the for is to algorithmically assign space within set dimensions. As such I need the data to not reorder and changing the dimensions of the chart isn't an option sadly/